# Errors in delivering static assets for Dash app in Shinyproxy

Tags: python, docker, plotly-dash, shinyproxy

I'm deploying Dash app on Shinyproxy using information from these posts:

> https://support.openanalytics.eu/t/what-is-the-best-way-of-delivering-static-assets-to-the-client-for-custom-apps/363
>
> https://lukesingham.com/how-to-deploy-plotlys-dash-using-shinyproxy/

Nevertheless, I get some errors when static assets should be delivered:

[image]

When I am running dash app in docker container everything is ok. There is not errors in the website and static assets are delivered.

My files:

**app.py**

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['my-style.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[

     html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

     html.Div(children='''
         Dash: A web application framework for Python.
     '''),

     html.Img(src='/assets/logo2.png'),

     dcc.Graph(
         id='example-graph',
         figure={
             'data': [
                 {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                 {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
             ],
             'layout': {
                 'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
             }
         }
      )
    ])

app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
app.config.update({
     'routes_pathname_prefix': ''
   , 'requests_pathname_prefix': ''
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8050, debug=True)
```

**application.yml**

```
port: 8080
authentication: simple
admin-groups: admins
users:
- name: admin
  password: admin
  groups: admins
docker:
  url: http://localhost:2375
specs:
- id: DashTest
  display-name: Dash Demo Application
  container-cmd: ["python", "app.py"]
  container-image: shiny-dash-app
  port: 8050
  access-groups: admins
logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

EDIT: My **code structure** looks like:

`dash
├── dash_shinyproxy 
|         ├── dashapp_shinyproxy 
|                     ├── Dockerfile 
|                     ├── app 
|                          ├── assets 
|                          ├── app.py`

Could anyone help me with this problem ? Has anyone recommended ideas on how static files should be served for shinyproxy?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is `my-style.css` a local file? In this case, no need to specify in the app as `dash` will automatically locate it for you. If it's non-local, make sure you have permission from the network to load the file. *(Hosting on Google Cloud storage using a global link as an example.)*

Comment: Yes, my-style.css is a local file. Dash app locate it automatically, nevertheless when I use Shinyproxy it is blocked.

Comment: hm, that's odd... just to be clear, when you **don't** define `external_stylesheets`, the specified css file is **not loaded**?

Comment: It appears the path in your app isn't configured correctly. Give me a second, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Try removing `host=` and `port=` from the final line in your code. Tell me if you get an error from that? @mariusz

Comment: Here's a link to more specific relative path settings: https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps

Comment: 1. Yes, when I don't define external_stylesheets, the specified css file is not loaded as well. 2. When I remove `host` and `port` and run docker and shinyproxy I got an error `Status code: 500 Message: Container did not respond in time`. 3. Please find my code structure in edited post.

Comment: is the folder `assets` in the same directory as your `app.yaml` and `app.py` ?

Comment: `assets` folder and `app.py`  are in the same directory (`app` diectory) . `app.yaml` with `shinyproxy.jar` are in different location.